# Razor does not working in a project but it works other in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I use visual studio 2012.Razor works this project.

https://ibb.co/tqNJpYt

But Razor doesn't work this project.

https://ibb.co/nrtBbQZ

How is it possible.I can't find solution.What do you suggest ? Thanks

Comment: The image links don't work, and even if they did you still need to include relevant information in the question itself.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a new version of ASP.NET Web Tools for VS 2012. After installing syntax highlighting is back again.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Installing VS 2012 Update 4 was not enough.

A set of offline installers is available. The offline installers are easier to use than the Web Platform Tools invoker (WebNode11Pack.exe @ ~114KB):

If you want an offline installer then please goto http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532

- AspNetWebTools2013_1Setup.exe @ ~39MB
- WebToolsExtensionsVS.msi (for Visual Studio 2012 standard edition[s])
  @ ~21MB
- WebToolsExtensionsVWD.msi (for Visual Studio 2012 free "Web"
  edition[s]) @ ~21MB

Comment: I tried that.But it doesn't work only one project.It works the others.